# How to completely remove New Relic application

Tags: centos, lfd

My server is running Centos 5.8 64 bit and I installed New Relic a short while ago to try and solve a few performance issues - as the server is not especially high spec I found it used too much system resources so I removed it using the Purge method as recommended on their site. https://newrelic.com/docs/general/how-do-i-uninstall-the-new-relic-agent#php

Even after doing this I keep getting messages from lfd warning about excess resource usage for New Relic and I dont know how to completely remove it. The warning from lfd is:

```
Time:         Sat Jan 26 10:31:14 2013 +0000
Account:      XXXXX
Resource:     Process Time
Exceeded:     30712 > 1800 (seconds)
Executable:   /usr/bin/newrelic-daemon
Command Line: /usr/bin/newrelic-daemon -l /var/log/newrelic/newrelic-daemon.log
PID:          1794 (Parent PID:1793)
Killed:       No
```

How can I get totally rid of New Relic?

Answer (score 7):

Had the same problem.

```
newrelic-install uninstall
```

did the trick for me

Comment: The instructions on their own site did not work for me, but this did the trick

Answer (score 2):

Did you *stop* the daemon? Simply uninstalling it would still leave it running.

Comment: @Jason As the startup scripts have probably gone for good during the uninstall, you might either issue a `killall newwelic-daemon` or restart your system to get rid of it.

Comment: Yes I did stop it - I did a ps -e and found and then killed two processes called newrelic but it restarts itself

Comment: Have just gone in and killed three running processes now and within a minute they have respawned. killall has made no difference, if I need to reboot then I will have to plan for it but I was hoping there would be a way of blocking the process from respawning

Answer (score 1):

If you are running newrelic in CentOS, try using yum or rpm commands to remove it, instead of the purge method described in their documentation.

1. stop the service
2. Uninstall it using either of the following commands -

   `yum remove newrelic-sysmond`

   `rpm -ev newrelic-sysmond`

Answer (score -3):

yum remove newrelic*

will work 1000%

Comment: Maybe for you, but it didn't fix the OP's actual issue.